# How do I list the tables where the records comes from?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have an array with some records retrieved from a Database. The array holds the primary key for a particular record from different tables.

What SQL can be used to retrieve an array with the name of those tables?

Visual representation:

```
TABLE = BABY_FOODS

NAME   |  H20_PERC   | ENERGY

CEREAL      1.6         100  

TABLE = BEEF_PRODUCTS

NAME   |  H20_PERC   | ENERGY

GOAT        75.8        400 

String[] selectedNames = {CEREAL, GOAT, HORSE, LETTUCE};

String[] tableNames = ? (Here, I'm trying to get BABY_FOODS, BEEF_PRODUCTS, etc)
```

Thank you

EDIT: The array size may change with the query.

I am using `Java`

my idea is to create a `Cursor` with this structure:

```
public Cursor selectTablesFromSearch(String value){
    String selectQuery = "SELECT TABLENAME WHERE THE VALUE HAS BEEN FOUND";

return myDataBase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, you want the table name associated with the primary key data you have. Am I getting your question right?

Comment: Correct. How can I find the table name associated with a particular value?

Comment: Ok fine, but please don't get me wrong with my next question. Will there be any value common with both primary keys ? or that particular key is available in multiple tables..Actually, looking for the table name with the data is not a good idea, though it is possible.

Comment: Yes, it could happen. Values could come from the same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `union` to select rows from multiple tables:

```
select  TableName
,       Name
from    (
        select  'BABY_FOODS' as TableName
        ,       Name
        from    BABY_FOODS
        union all
        select  'BEEF_PRODUCTS'
        ,       Name
        from    BEEF_PRODUCTS
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   Name in ('CEREAL', 'GOAT', 'HORSE', 'LETTUCE')
```

The first part of a union determines the column names.  The second (and further) parts can safely omit the `as` clause.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I'm trying to find the table name. Not trying to select more rows. If I have a particular value from an unknown table, how can I find that table?

Comment: I've added a `where` statement that you can use to locate a row.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to understand the query. In "select 'table2' " does it need "as TableName" like in the first part?

Comment: I changed my question a little bit. Could you take a look at it please?

Comment: What if primaryKey1 is not found on Table1?

Comment: The where clause now looks for multiple values.  You could try it out to see what happens when a key is not found :)